# Plotting multiple plots with two discrete variables - how to include all discrete variables in both axes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
test<-data.frame("M"=c("a","b","c","a","b","b","c","a","b","c"), 
                 "N"=c(1,3,4,6,6,7,7,8,8,8), 
                 "X"=c(0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1), 
                 "Y"=c(1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0))
```

I'm making a simple plot where I want `X` and `Y` on the y axis, `M` on the x axis, each grid colored if the value of `X` or `Y` is `1` and empty if the value of `X` or `Y` is `0`. I'm repeating this for each categories in `N` (the categories of `N` are `1 to 5`, `6`, `7`, `8`), then stacking all plots together. Right now, I'm doing this with the following code.

```
test <- test[order(test$N),]
test1 <- test[c(1:3),]
test2 <- test[c(4:5),]
test3 <- test[c(6:7),]
test4 <- test[c(8:10),]   # I'm doing this to "separate" categories of `N` manually

p1 <- test1[,c(1,3:4)] %>%
  gather(col_name, value, -M) %>%
  ggplot(aes(factor(M), col_name, fill = value == 1))+
  geom_tile(colour = 'black')+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('FALSE' = 'white', 'TRUE' = 'red'))
p2 <- test2[,c(1,3:4)] %>%
  gather(col_name, value, -M) %>%
  ggplot(aes(factor(M), col_name, fill = value == 1))+
  geom_tile(colour = 'black')+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('FALSE' = 'white', 'TRUE' = 'yellow'))
p3 <- test3[,c(1,3:4)] %>%
  gather(col_name, value, -M) %>%
  ggplot(aes(factor(M), col_name, fill = value == 1))+
  geom_tile(colour = 'black')+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('FALSE' = 'white', 'TRUE' = 'green'))
p4 <- test4[,c(1,3:4)] %>%
  gather(col_name, value, -M) %>%
  ggplot(aes(factor(M), col_name, fill = value == 1))+
  geom_tile(colour = 'black')+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('FALSE' = 'white', 'TRUE' = 'blue'))

grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, p4, ncol = 1)
```

[image: the plot I have after running the code above]

I'm attaching an image of what I have right now. I want to fix these plots so that I would have the same factors of `M` for all four plots (right now, only `p1` and `p4` have all three factors (`a`, `b` and `c`) in the x axis but I want to add factor `c` to `p2` and `a` to `p3` so that all x axes are identical to each other. Can anyone give me suggestions on how to do this?

(Also, I'm suspecting that the current way I'm plotting things is probably not the most quickest/easiest way to go, if anyone has suggestions on how to improve things it'd be really helpful!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe one approach I can suggest you is using facets after applying a smart trick to group your values and avoid splitting in different dataframes. Here the code as an option for you (The colors will be the same across the facets in base of `TRUE/FALSE` values):

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
test %>% mutate(Var=lead(N)) %>%
  mutate(Diff=Var-N,Diff=ifelse(row_number()==1,0,Diff)) %>%
  mutate(Group=ifelse(Diff==0,N,NA)) %>%
  fill(Group) %>% select(-c(N,Var,Diff)) %>%
  group_by(Group) %>% mutate(NG=paste0('p',cur_group_id())) %>% ungroup() %>%
  select(-Group) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(NG,M)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(factor(M), name, fill = value == 1,group=value))+
  geom_tile(colour = 'black')+
  facet_wrap(.~NG,ncol = 1)+
  scale_fill_manual('value',values=c('tomato','cyan3'))+
  xlab('M')
```

Output:

[image]

The othe option would be `patchwork` with a customized function:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)
#Code
data <- test %>% mutate(Var=lead(N)) %>%
  mutate(Diff=Var-N,Diff=ifelse(row_number()==1,0,Diff)) %>%
  mutate(Group=ifelse(Diff==0,N,NA)) %>%
  fill(Group) %>% select(-c(N,Var,Diff)) %>%
  group_by(Group) %>% mutate(NG=paste0('p',cur_group_id())) %>% ungroup() %>%
  select(-Group) %>%
  mutate(M=factor(M,levels = unique(M),ordered = T)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(NG,M))
#List
List <- split(data,data$NG)
#Function
myfun <- function(x)
{
  #Test for color
  val <- unique(x$NG)
  #Conditioning for color
  if(val=='p1') {vcolor=c('FALSE' = 'white', 'TRUE' = 'red')} else
    if(val=='p2') {vcolor=c('FALSE' = 'white', 'TRUE' = 'yellow')} else
      if(val=='p3') {vcolor=c('FALSE' = 'white', 'TRUE' = 'green')} else
      {vcolor=c('FALSE' = 'white', 'TRUE' = 'blue')}
  #Update data
  x <- x %>% mutate(M=factor(M,levels = c('a','b','c'),ordered = T)) %>% complete(M=M)
  #Plot
  G <- ggplot(x,aes(factor(M), name, fill = (value == 1 & !is.na(value))))+
    geom_tile(colour = 'black')+
    scale_fill_manual('value',values=vcolor)+
    xlab('M')+
    scale_y_discrete(limits=c('X','Y'))+
    theme_bw()+
    ggtitle(val)
  return(G)
}
#Apply
Lplot <- lapply(List,myfun)
#Wrap
GF <- wrap_plots(Lplot,ncol = 1)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi Duck, this looks like a really smart way! I'm just trying to correctly understand what you did in your first solution - so you're finding the next value of `N` for each row and saving that as `Var`, then calculate `Diff`, and assign a distinct `Group` when `Diff` isn't `0` except for the first row. I'm assuming this is only possible because my bin for `N` in this dataset was `1 to 5`, `6`, `7`, `8` so setting groups by `Diff` value of `0` worked? For example, if I want a different bin for `N` (`1 to 5`, `6`, `7 to 8`, `9`), now the `6` and `7 to 8` bin wouldn't be separated?

Comment: @Jen Yeah the trick for automatic plots is hacking the groups. The first group have different elements so I set as 1 then the other groups have at least one duplicated. So using lead you will put up that value so that when you compute the difference it will be zero and then you can assign a common index for the groups and the rest is done by the functions. I hope that was clear enough for you :)

Answer (score 1):

To continue using `grid.arrange()`, instead of `facet_wrap()`, do the following:

Make `M` a factor:

```
test$M <- factor(test$M)
```

Add the following to each of your plots:

```
scale_x_discrete(limits = levels(test$M))
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Sorry I can't accept multiple answers at once

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
test<-data.frame("M"=c("a","b","c","a","b","b","c","a","b","c"), 
                 "N"=c(1,3,4,6,6,7,7,8,8,8), 
                 "X"=c(0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1), 
                 "Y"=c(1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0))

library(tidyverse)

test = mutate(test, N2 = cut(N, breaks = c(0,5:100)))    
m = pivot_longer(test, c(X, Y))

ggplot(m, aes(M, name,fill=factor(value))) +
    geom_tile(colour = 'black') +
    facet_wrap(~N2, scales = 'free') +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c(`0` = 'white', `1` = 'red'))
```